# Error when updating row in a Kendo grid with a model with datetimeoffset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid with a model that contains two datetimeoffset properties, just to show when a row was created and modified. They are just displayed in the grid and are not editable. Here is an abbreviated example of the model:

```
public class ConfigurationParameterSelectorViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string CurrentValue { get; set; }    
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

There are more properties than that, but has been removed for readability.
So in this case, only "CurrentValue" property can be edited in the grid, and when it is edited and then posted to the controller method, the DateTimeOffset values are suddenly null, which makes the ModelState invalid and the following error is thrown:

> The value '/Date(1590480680003)/' is not valid for CreatedDate. The
> value '/Date(1596443007283)/' is not valid for ModifiedDate.

As far as I know, this has something to do with DateTimeOffset being parsed incorrectly in json when sent to the controller. To be honest I know very little of this so it's a bit difficult to describe correctly.

It works as intended if I convert the DateTimeOffset values from the database to a regular DateTime object, but then I no longer have the timezone.

I don't think it's necessary to show the grid code as it's a regular kendo mvc grid with DataSource set to use Ajax, though I can supply it on request.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know about this. Have you seen this? https://feedback.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/1430496-support-binding-of-grid-columns-to-datetimeoffset-fields  There is a recent post from June 2020 there with knowledge base and example links. KB link: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/knowledge-base/datetimepicker-datetimeoffset-bind-to-model

Comment: @G_P thank you for your reply. Yeah I have seen it, but that solution doesn't seem right and more of a hack if you ask me. Implementing automapper and suddenly having to deal with that is overkill I think, and I had hoped there was a better solution than "just convert your datetimeoffset to datetime in the viewmodel".

Comment: I get what you're saying, but it is a 'hack' straight from Telerik, so I'm not sure what other options you have for now... Also, you could get around having to use automapper and do the mapping yourself

Comment: Yeah it's late, but in the end I opted to just directly convert DateTimeOffset's from the database to regular DateTimes in the viewmodels, and using a DateTime extension to convert the timezone when getting the date.